# Changing position of picture in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

How could I move the position of my image to the top left corner?

```
RedStartImg = Canvas(display, width = 100, height = 100)
RedStartImg.pack()
RedStart = PhotoImage(file="0.png")
RedStartImg.create_image(10,10, anchor=NW, image=RedStart)
```

Is there something wrong with the other code that is making this code not function properly?

Comment: What have you tried to "move the position of your image to the top left corner"? How did it fail to meet your expectations? [Asking on Stack Overflow is not a substitute for doing your own research.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/843953)

Comment: What I have tried was to change the numbers in this: RedStartImg.create_image(10,10, anchor=SW, image=RedStart) to the top left corner, but instead it stays in the same spot and cuts the picture.

Comment: Can you give an expected output? Its hard to understand from the screenshot about your entire window.

Comment: @TealBlue Try removing: `width = 100, height = 100`

Comment: Try `RedStartImg.pack(anchor="w", fill="x")`.